# haxe -xml command line example

Tags: xml, command-line, haxe

I want to go through all of my haxe classes and generate xml from the comments.

I see there is a built-in haxe command:

haxe -xml

However I don't know how to use it for my situation.

I want to go through all of the haxe classes in my directory (called framework) and output the xml. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation:](http://haxe.org/doc/compiler)

> -xml `<file>`: generate XML types description of all input classes. (normaly used for documentation)

If you want the full project to be included, You can use this in combination with `haxe --macro include('my.package')` This forces the inclusion of all the files defined in a given package and its sub packages. See http://haxe.org/manual/macros_compiler

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason why this wasn't working for me is because I was trying to document a framework that has no build file - the specific implementation has a build file but not the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax:

haxe buildfile.hxml -xml outputfile.xml

also

haxe -xml outputfile.xml buildfile.hxml

you must have a valid build file for this to work.